# please explain how to use split in this piece of homework

Tags: python, list, split

Instructions:

If we don't know how many items are in a file, we can use read() to load the entire file and then use the line endings (the \n bits) to split it into lines. Here is an example of how to use split()

```
source = 'aaa,bbb,ccc'
things = source.split(',') # split at every comma
print(things) # displays ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] because things is a list
```

Task

Ask the user to enter names and keep asking until they enter nothing.

Add each new name to a file called names.txt as they are entered.

Hint: Open the file before the loop and close it after the loop

Once they have stopped entering names, load the file contents, split it into individual lines and print the lines one by one with -= before the name and =- after it.

Comment: It looks as though its already been split up into sub tasks

Comment: so how would i use split to split the lines and put -= =-

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the file of names called `input.txt` like so:

```
Tom
Dick
Harry
```

Then the code to read the entire file, split on `'\n'` and print each name in the required format is

```
# Open the file
with open("input.txt") as file:
    # Read the entire file
    content = file.read()

    # Split the content up into individual names
    names = content.split('\n')

    # Print the required string for each name
    for name in names:
        print(f'-={name}=-')
```

Hope that solves your problem.